# Question about CentOS shared sftp directory and additional drive space

Tags: centos, sftp

We have an SFTP server (CentOS) set up to give our clients larger files.
We set each user up with the following commands:

```
useradd -g sftpgroup -d /data1 -s /sbin/nologin user1
passwd user1
mkdir /sftp/user1/
mkdir /sftp/user1/data
chown user1:sftpgroup /sftp/user1/data/
```

and the same thing for user2.

This allows our clients to use WinScp to log into the sftp - automatically landing in their own data directory.
Each client's data directory resides on the server in `/sftp/user#/data`

We have two current issues.

1. our sda has become full, and
2. we have several very large files that we need to share with at least 6 clients.

We have mounted a new sdb and configured it with `/data/sftpdata`

Questions:

1. how do I put a shared directory in /data/sftpdata/shareddocs and make it available to the clients winscp login?
   Possibly with something like a shortcut in each data directory?
2. If I create a new user with

   ```
   useradd -g sftpgroup -d /data1 -s /sbin/nologin user3
   passwd user3
   mkdir /data/sftpdata/user3/
   mkdir /data/sftpdata/user3/data
   chown user1:sftpgroup /data/sftpdata/user3/data/
   ```

   would that work to create a new user, but use the new drive? Or is there something else embedded in CentOS that needs to be set?

Comment: Apologize for my wording - what I was looking at was to add user3 etc using the new drive - code line corrected - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answered the second part of my question myself.

Wound up adding all of sdb to `/dev/vg_server/vm_root` which allowed me to post the data for my other users.

But this is still a space wasting answer.

I am still hoping to find instruction on allowing several jailed users to see a directory of "shared" information.

Every time I think I have it set up (as root) when I test as the user, the shortcut tells me they don't have the rights.

Any guidance on where to read up on an answer would be appreciated.